# How to make avg_over_time with variable interval in prometheus request?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

What I need is to make avg_over_time with variable interval from today 00:00 till now, but I cant do it.

What I already tried

```
avg_over_time(solarpanel_power{job="arduino"}[hour() + "h"])
```

and different variations to add time unit, nothing worked i also tried grafana variables like
[${__range_s}s]
But it not variable it always same. I could do [24h] but this mean that yesterday values could influence, which i dont want.

Answer (score 1):

In Grafana you can select "Today so far" in the time range selector and the following query:

```
avg_over_time(solarpanel_power{job="arduino"}[$__range])
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, except cant find a way to override time range for this exact panel. If i set this  "Today so far" it works fine, but when i need to change it it also change $__range and broke everything